# Incrementally add data to Parquet tables in S3

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I would like to keep a copy of my log data in in Parquet on S3 for ad hoc analytics. I mainly work with Parquet through Spark and that only seems to offer operations to read and write whole tables via `SQLContext.parquetFile()` and `SQLContext.saveAsParquetFile()`.

Is there any way to add data to and existing Parquet table
without writing a whole new copy of it
particularly when it is stored in S3?

I know I can create separate tables for the updates and in Spark I can form the union of the corresponig DataFrames in Spark at query time but I have my doubts about the scalability of that.

I can use something other than Spark if needed.

Answer (score 4):

The way to append to a parquet file is using `SaveMode.Append`

```
`yourDataFrame.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).parquet("/your/file")`
```

Comment: Do you have a soruce for this?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to union `DataFrames` after creating them separately, just supply all the paths related to your query to the `parquetFile(paths)` and get one `DataFrame`. Just as the signature of reading parquet file: `sqlContext.parquetFile(paths: String*)` suggests.

Under the hood, in `newParquetRelation2`, all the `.parquet` files from all the folders you supply, as well as all the `_common_medata` and `_metadata` would be filled into a [single list](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/parquet/newParquet.scala#L279-287) and regard equally.

Comment: I this as efficient to query as a single table?

Comment: @DanielMahler, I think the difference could be neglect, just need to handle one more `_metadata` file which takes no time, I think